# Google signin dialogFragment returns null as Intent data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am trying to integrate google signin in my app test app. The problem i am facing is with the startActivityForResult from the Fragment opens a diaologFragment for selecting the emaild id which after selecting returns null in Intent data. Also i noticed that it calls the onActivityResult of MainActivity instead of fragment's onActivityResult.

Fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    Log.d("DisplayImage","onCreateView--------------------------------");
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    Log.d("DisplayImage","onAttach--------------------------------");
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    Log.d("DisplayImage","onStart--------------------------------");
    super.onStart();
    if (!mResolvingError) {
        Log.d("DisplayImage","-----------mGoogleApiClient.connect() called--------------------------------");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    Log.d("DisplayImage","-----------mGoogleApiClient.disconnect() called--------------------------------");
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("DisplayImage","onStop--------------------------------");

}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("DisplayImage","onConnected--------------------------------");
    textView_testConnection.setText("Connection Successful");

        Log.d("DisplayImage","Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)="+Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)+"----------------");
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            textView_testConnection.setText("Connection Successful personName="+personName+" email="+email);

        }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d("DisplayImage","onConnectionSuspended--------------------------------");
    textView_testConnection.setText("Connection Suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d("DisplayImage", "onConnectionFailed--------------------------------" +  "...hasConnectedApi()"+connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    textView_testConnection.setText("Connection Failed");
    if(mResolvingError){
        return;
    }else if(connectionResult.hasResolution()){
        Log.d("DisplayImage","connectionResult.hasResolution():Returned true--------------------------------");
        try{
            mResolvingError=true;
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(),RC_SIGN_IN);
            Log.d("DisplayImage","connectionResult.startResolutionForResult() called"+"--------------------------------");
        }catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.d("DisplayImage","mGoogleApiClient.connect() called-----------------");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }else{
        showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        mResolvingError=true;
    }
}

private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode){
    Log.d("DisplayImage","showErrorDialog--------------------------------");
    ErrorDialogFragment dialogFragment=new ErrorDialogFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DIALOG_ERROR,errorCode);
    dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
    dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"errordialog");
}

public void onDialogDismissed(){
    mResolvingError=false;
}
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public ErrorDialogFragment(){}

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("DisplayImage","onCreateDialog() Called------------------------------");
        int errorCode=this.getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ERROR);
        Log.d("DisplayImage","errorCode="+errorCode+"-------------------");
        return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this.getActivity(), REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
//            onDialogDismissed();
        new DisplayImage().onDialogDismissed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    Log.d("DisplayImage","onActivityResult--------------------------------");
    if(data!=null){
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
        mResolvingError = false;
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                    !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
    }else{
        Log.d("DisplayImage","Intent data="+data);
    }
}
```

COde in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DisplayImage.OnFragmentInteractionListener {    
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("MainActivity","This is being called hence the error.......");
    Fragment
Fragment fragment=getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.lm_fragment);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data); 
}
```

LogCat:

```
> D/MainActivity﹕ onStart--------------------------------  
D/DisplayImage﹕ onStart--------------------------------  
D/DisplayImage﹕ -----------mGoogleApiClient.connect() called--------------------------------  
D/DisplayImage﹕mGoogleApiClient.hasConnected()--------------------------------false  
D/MainActivity﹕ onResume--------------------------------  
D/DisplayImage﹕ onResume--------------------------------  
I/MediaPlayer﹕ Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0  
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set  
D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0  
D/DisplayImage﹕ onConnectionFailed--------------------------------  ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{427ec270: android.os.BinderProxy@427ec210}}...hasConnectedApi()4
D/DisplayImage﹕ connectionResult.hasResolution():Returned true--------------------------------  
D/DisplayImage﹕ connectionResult.startResolutionForResult()--------------------------------  
D/DisplayImage﹕ onPause--------------------------------  
D/MainActivity﹕ onPause--------------------------------  
D/MainActivity﹕ This is being called hence the error.......  
D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM  
W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41becc08)  
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
    Process: ..., PID: 5498  
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {.../MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException  
            at  android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3681)  
            at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3724)
```

Hence my questions:

1. Is there a way that fragments onActivityResult can be called directly?
2. Why does the signin dialog returns Intent data?

This is the first time m trying google signin... and first time with fragments as well...